# How to choose the best marks with specified credits in c programming?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to make a program to get the weighted average (`formula = (mark*(credits corresponds to it))/total credits`) from the `best(highest) 120 credits module` from the following marks and credits (the credits corresponds to the module):

```
module[12]={48, 77, 46, 82, 85, 43, 49, 73, 65, 48, 47, 51}

credits[12]={60, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 10}
```

What I have done is bubble sort the array, so that the array is sorted by decreasing manner to know which marks is higher, as shown below:

```
module[12]={85, 82, 77, 73, 65, 51, 49, 48, 48, 47, 46, 43}

credits[12]={10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 60, 20, 20, 20, 20}
```

And then I need to choose the best 120 credits module from the sorted array **so that the weighted average will be maximum**, but then I have no idea where to start. =(

Someone help me! Thanks a lot!

EDIT: 
I have tried to work out the code myself, and eventually get the following code, it works, but for some special case it stop working =(

```
float credits=0, result=0;
n=0;

struct{
    float credits;
    float result;
    float n;
    float addpoint;
}point;

while (credits < 120){
        credits+=credits[n];
        result+=(result[n]*credits[n]);
        n++; 
    }

    if (credits != 120){
        credits -= credits[n-1];
        result -= (result[n-1]*credits[n-1]);

        point.credits = credits;
        point.result = result;
        point.n = (n-1)-1;

        point.addpoint = n;

again:  while (credits < 120){
            credits+=credits[n];
            result+=(result[n]*credits[n]);
            n++;
        }

        if (credits != 120){
            point.credits -= credits[point.n-1];
            point.result -= result[point.n-1]*credits[point.n-1];
            point.n--;

            credits = point.credits;
            result = point.result;
            n = point.addpoint-1;

            goto again;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Solved. Using knapsack problem code/integer linear programming by the application of glpk

Comment: "best" is a pretty vague term, see above how you can properly formulate a question.

Comment: What language ? C or C++ ? (They are two very different languages.)

Comment: @PaulR; These tags together are very dangerous (specially when one of them removed after providing your answer).

Comment: Yes, I think I didnt explain enough. Will edit

Comment: I'm using c language. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm a newbie here

Comment: Dynamic programming ? Knapsack-problem ?

Comment: I am not sure, Im just learning basic c programming.. and my lecturer ask us to do this stuff..

Comment: Knapsack answers the question: what combination of those courses provides best weighted average. I tried it, and I get the best weighted average at 70 credits, not at 120. May be some modification of knapsack is in order.

Comment: @joop,@Arkadiy Thanks so much for mentioning the key word for solving this kind of problem. I myself don't know this is a knapsack problem/integer linear problem, after searching the net I gained a lot of useful information. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way, which is practical for small examples like the one you've got, is to use dynamic programming. One can build up a table of "optimal score if you use the first k subjects, and want credits to add up to T". The code's a bit messy because C doesn't make it particularly easy to have dynamically sized 2d arrays, but here's a solution. Probably your professor was expecting something along these lines.

A small note, I divided all the credits (and the target credits of 120) by 10 because the common factor was redundant, but the code works just fine without that (it'll just use a tad more memory and time).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

#define GET(t, i, j, n) ((t)[(i) * (n + 1) + j])

// optimize_marks takes arrays creds and marks (both of length n),
// and finds a subset I of 0..(n-1) that maximizes
// sum(i in I)creds[i]*marks[i], such that sum(i in I)creds[i] = total.
void optimize_marks(size_t n, int *creds, int *marks, int total) {
    // tbl[k * (total + 1) + T] stores the optimal score using only the
    // first k subjects for a total credit score of T.
    // tbl[n * (total + 1) + total] will be the final result.
    // A score of -1 means that the result is impossible.
    int *tbl = malloc((n + 1) * (total + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int T = 0; T <= total; T++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                // With 0 subjects, the best score is 0 if 0 credits are
                // required. If more than 0 credits are required, the result
                // is impossible.
                GET(tbl, i, T, total) = -(T > 0);
                continue;
            }
            // One way to get T credits with the first i subjects is to
            // get T credits with the first (i-1) subjects.
            GET(tbl, i, T, total) = GET(tbl, i - 1, T, total);
            // The other way is to use the marks for the i'th subject
            // and get the rest of the credits with the first (i-1) subjects.
            // We have to check that it's possible to use the first (i-1) subjects
            // to get the remainder of the credits.
            if (T >= creds[i-1] && GET(tbl, i - 1, T - creds[i-1], total) >= 0) {
                // Pick the best of using and not using the i'th subject.
                GET(tbl, i, T, total) = max(
                    GET(tbl, i, T, total),
                    GET(tbl, i - 1, T - creds[i-1], total) + marks[i-1] * creds[i-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    int T = total;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        if (GET(tbl, i - 1, T, total) < GET(tbl, i, T, total)) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", i, creds[i-1], marks[i-1]);
            T -= creds[i-1];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int creds[] = {6, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
    int marks[] = {48, 77, 46, 82, 85, 43, 49, 73, 65, 48, 47, 51};
    optimize_marks(12, creds, marks, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

The program gives the solution as the ILP program:

```
12 1 51
11 2 47
10 2 48
9 1 65
8 1 73
5 1 85
4 2 82
2 2 77
```

Comment: This is more a c programming approach, which I would prefer more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an integer linear programming problem. You want to find a vector [x1 x2 x3 ... x12] where each of the x's is either 0 or 1, such that sum(x[i] * cred[i]) = 120 and that sum(x[i] * cred[i] * marks[i]) is maximised.

There's a large body of research in how to solve such problems, but there's existing solvers out there and ready for you to use and using them is going to save you a vast amount of time over coding a solver up yourself.

Here's a module file for glpk, a free linear programming and integer linear programming solver. You can run it by installing glpk, saving this to a file then running `glpsol -m <filename>`

```
set I := 1..12;
var x{I} binary;
param cred{I};
param marks{I};

maximize s:
    sum{i in I}(x[i] * cred[i] * marks[i]);
s.t. totalcreds: sum{i in I}(x[i] * cred[i]) = 120;

solve;
printf {i in I} "%d: %d %d %d\n", i, x[i], cred[i], marks[i];

data;

param cred := 1 60, 2 20, 3 20, 4 20, 5 10, 6 20, 7 10, 8 10, 9 10, 10 20, 11 20, 12 10;
param marks := 1 48, 2 77, 3 46, 4 82, 5 85, 6 43, 7 49, 8 73, 9 65, 10 48, 11 47, 12 51;

end;
```

The output is this:

```
1: 0 60 48
2: 1 20 77
3: 0 20 46
4: 1 20 82
5: 1 10 85
6: 0 20 43
7: 0 10 49
8: 1 10 73
9: 1 10 65
10: 1 20 48
11: 1 20 47
12: 1 10 51
```

That is, you should pick courses 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 (ie: the courses with a '1' by them).

Comment: Yes, the features of GLPK are exposed through a C library. You need to go to http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/ to download it, and there's documentation included.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by isolating all the combinaisons of credits[] elements whose sum equals 120 and store them before calculating all the means.
It would look like that :

```
// test for all possible combinaisons :
 // [0] + [1] + [2]..., [1] + [0] + [2]...
// starting point on the array : n
 while(n < 12){
    // if the sum isnt equal to 120 and 
   // we havent covered all the array yet
   if(temp < 120 && i < 12){
         // if i is different from the starting point
         if(i < 11 && i != n){
           i++;
           temp += credits[i];
           // store i
         }
    }
    if(temp >120 && i < 11){
            temp -= credits[i];
            // remove i
            i++;
     }
    if(temp == 120){
           // starting point ++
           n++;
     }
 }
```

It's not optimal, but it could work.

Comment: can you explain more on why you use _if (i < 11 && i !=n)_ and also _if (temp >120 && i <11)_ ?
i understand the concept you proposed, but i just dont get this part.
Thanks in advance!